# path to casperjs if I install it from git?

Tags: git, path, phantomjs, echo, casperjs

I already tried to install it from `master branch`

- I downloaded casperj-master-branch.zip file, but there is this error about versions:

> bin/bootstrap.js: in __die

So i decided to install right from git using shell.

```
git clone git://github.com/n1k0/casperjs.git
$ cd casperjs
$ ln -sf `pwd`/bin/casperjs /usr/local/bin/casperjs
```

I did these commands in shell on mac.
It installed somewhere.
Now I need to set path to it like this:

```
echo $PATH
export PATH="phantomjsdir:/path_to_casper"
```

Except that I don't know where to look for path_to_casper!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [installation from git](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installing-from-git) simply consists in a symbolic link:

```
 /usr/local/bin/casperjs => `pwd`/bin/casperjs
```

That means the path of `casperjs` is in `/usr/local/bin/`, which is already in your `PATH`.
You can confirm it with a `which casperjs`.

Comment: in windows it is "where casperjs" , where phantomjs